# chromium_browser garbled in text box when copy and paste

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, update, chromium

I am Japanese and used to use Japanese and English characters togeter.
When I copy text from some program to chromium-browser in-box, it garbles.
Garbles (mis-conversion) happens between some program and chromium but not happen inside chromiums.

For example, I open text editor(leafpad) and type "*abcあいう*" and copy this, then paste it some inbox(URL/Search box) of chromium, it garbles like: *abc\u3042\u3044\u3046*　
　* but not garbles inside chromium themselves.

My chromium version is 88.0.4324.187 (Official Built) on Raspbian.
I guess this happens recently but I never experienced before.
Same thing above between Firefox and leafpad works.

Thanks, Shigeru

Comment: What is the contents of `/etc/default/locale`?

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but: It isn't garbled in the sense of getting replaced with nonsense.  Those are unicode point values, eg. `\u3042` is "HIRAGANA LETTER A" (あ): https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

Comment: thanks for your response

/etc/default/locale　is below:






#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ja_JP.UTF-8